# contents in python print function is not printed out

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, printing

```
def recv():

while True:
    data = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    content, address = data
    ip, port = address
    print('\r>>>[%s %d] %s' % (ip, port, content.decode()))
    print('<<<', end='')
```

When I call this function, the content in the last `print` function (the last line of codes) is not printed out. Anybody knows why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The standard output stream is buffered so it is likely that the `<<<` is in the buffer and would be flushed the next time that a newline is written.  Try removing the `end=''`.  You can also switch to using `sys.stderr` which (I believe) is unbuffered.

Comment: Why is it buffered?